Can't Navigate to the next page while web scrapin
I was trying to extract the required skills to work as a data analyst to make an analysis project to know the most wanted skills
My code is working fine till the part of navigating to the next page to extract the rest of the jobs information
But i have been trying to do that for two days
I don't know what is the problem
But i think it is the button selector or something
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import os
import csv
import time

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\BraveSoftware\\Brave-Browser\\Application\\brave.exe"
driver_path = "C:\\Users\\Alaa\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(driver_path), options=options)



def getJobInfo(job_link): 
    try:
        driver.get(job_link)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # wait up to 10 seconds
        jobTitle = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1.css-f9uh36'))).text.strip()
        try:
            company = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.css-tdvcnh'))).text
        except Exception as e:
            companylist = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.css-9iujih')
            company = companylist[0].text
        date = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.css-182mrdn').text.strip()
        job_type = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.css-g65o95'))).text
        location_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//strong[contains(@class, "css-9geu3q")]')))
        location = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].textContent", location_element).split("-")[-1].strip()
        listt= driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.css-4xky9y')
        experience = listt[0].text if len(listt) > 0 else None
        salary = listt[3].text if len(listt) > 3 else None
        skills = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.css-1t5f0fr').text
        return {
            "Job Title": jobTitle,
            "Company": company,
            "Date": date,
            "Job type": job_type,
            "Location": location,
            "Experience": experience,
            "Salary": salary,
            "Skills": skills
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None

# Navigate to the main page
driver.get("https://wuzzuf.net/search/jobs/?q=data+analyst&a=na")

# Initialize an empty list to store all job information
allJobInfo = []


current_url = driver.current_url  # Initialize current_url

while True:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Get the job detail page URLs
    jobsList = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.css-1gatmva.e1v1l3u10')
    job_links = [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.css-o171kl').get_attribute('href') for job in jobsList]

    print(f"Found {len(job_links)} job links on this page.")

    for job_link in job_links:
        print(f"Visiting job link: {job_link}")
        jobInfo = getJobInfo(job_link)
        if jobInfo is not None:
            allJobInfo.append(jobInfo)
            print(f"Successfully scraped job info from {job_link}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to scrape job info from {job_link}")
        time.sleep(2)

    # Try to click the 'Next' button to go to the next page
    try:
        next_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.css-1rodp7n.ezfki8j0')))

        # Check if the 'Next' button is clickable (optional)
        if 'disabled' not in next_button.get_attribute('class'):
            print("Next button is enabled.")
            current_url = driver.current_url  # Store the current URL
            print("Current URL before clicking Next:", current_url)

            # Use JavaScript to click the 'Next' button
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
            time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds (adjust as needed)

            # Store the job links of the current page
            prev_job_links = job_links

            # Get the job links of the new page
            new_jobsList = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.css-1gatmva.e1v1l3u10')
            new_job_links = [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.css-o171kl').get_attribute('href') for job in new_jobsList]

            # Compare the job links
            if new_job_links != prev_job_links:
                print("Successfully navigated to the next page.")
            else:
                print("Failed to navigate to the next page.")

        else:
            print("Reached the last page. The 'Next' button is disabled.")
            break

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Reached the last page or element not found.")
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to navigate to the next page. Error: {e}")
        break
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Get the job detail page URLs
    jobsList = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.css-1gatmva.e1v1l3u10')
    job_links = [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.css-o171kl').get_attribute('href') for job in jobsList]

    print(f"Found {len(job_links)} job links on this page.")
    counter = 0  # Initialize counter

    for job_link in job_links:
        if counter == 1:  # If counter is 1, break the loop
            break
        print(f"Visiting job link: {job_link}")
        jobInfo = getJobInfo(job_link)
        if jobInfo is not None:
            allJobInfo.append(jobInfo)
            print(f"Successfully scraped job info from {job_link}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to scrape job info from {job_link}")
        time.sleep(2)
        counter += 1  # Increment counter at the end of each loop

    # Try to click the 'Next' button to go to the next page
    try:
        next_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.css-1rodp7n.ezfki8j0')))

        # Check if the 'Next' button is clickable (optional)
        if 'disabled' not in next_button.get_attribute('class'):
            print("Next button is enabled.")
            current_url = driver.current_url  # Store the current URL
            print("Current URL before clicking Next:", current_url)
            next_button.click()  # Click the 'Next' button
            time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds (adjust as needed)

            # Store the job links of the current page
            prev_job_links = job_links

            # Get the job links of the new page
            new_jobsList = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.css-1gatmva.e1v1l3u10')
            new_job_links = [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.css-o171kl').get_attribute('href') for job in new_jobsList]

            # Compare the job links
            if new_job_links != prev_job_links:
                print("Successfully navigated to the next page.")
            else:
                print("Failed to navigate to the next page.")

        else:
            print("Reached the last page. The 'Next' button is disabled.")
            break

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Reached the last page or element not found.")
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to navigate to the next page. Error: {e}")
        break
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Get the job detail page URLs
    jobsList = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.css-1gatmva.e1v1l3u10')
    job_links = [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.css-o171kl').get_attribute('href') for job in jobsList]

    print(f"Found {len(job_links)} job links on this page.")
    counter = 0  # Initialize counter

    for job_link in job_links:
        if counter == 1:  # If counter is 1, break the loop
            break
        print(f"Visiting job link: {job_link}")
        jobInfo = getJobInfo(job_link)
        if jobInfo is not None:
            allJobInfo.append(jobInfo)
            print(f"Successfully scraped job info from {job_link}")
        else:
            print(f"Failed to scrape job info from {job_link}")
        time.sleep(2)
        counter += 1  # Increment counter at the end of each loop

    # Try to click the 'Next' button to go to the next page
    try:
        next_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.css-1rodp7n.ezfki8j0')))


        # Check if the 'Next' button is clickable (optional)
        if 'disabled' not in next_button.get_attribute('class'):
            print("Next button is enabled.")
            current_url = driver.current_url  # Store the current URL
            print("Current URL before clicking Next:", current_url)
            next_button.click()  # Click the 'Next' button
            time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds (adjust as needed)

        # Check for successful navigation (alternative approach)
            if wait.until(EC.url_to_be(current_url + "&page=2")):  # Check for specific URL pattern
                print("Successfully navigated to the next page.")
            else:
                print("Failed to navigate to the next page. URL pattern mismatch.")
        else:
            print("Reached the last page. The 'Next' button is disabled.")
            break

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Reached the last page or element not found.")
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to navigate to the next page. Error: {e}")
        break


driver.quit()


keys = allJobInfo[0].keys() if allJobInfo else []  # Adjusting for empty jobInfo list
filename = "jobs.csv"
path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", filename)

if allJobInfo:
    with open(path, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as webscraping:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(webscraping, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        for job in allJobInfo:
            match_encoded = {k: v.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8') if isinstance(v, str) else v for k, v in job.items()}
            dict_writer.writerow(match_encoded)
        print(f"File '{filename}' saved to Desktop.")
else:
    print("No jobs found.")

that is the page that I'm trying to extract the data from  wuzzuf_website
I tried many ways to select the next button and nothing worked

Try this in your browser:
document.querySelectorAll('button.css-1rodp7n.ezfki8j0');
While the first selector targets a button with specific classes, it might not be working because the class names seem to be dynamically generated.
Here's an alternative approach using the button's path in the HTML structure:
document.querySelector("#app > div > div.css-1omce3u > div > div > div.css-if9uys > ul > li:last-child > button");

Note that I've updated li:nth-child(7)  to li:last-child as the next page button should be the last one. The browser finds it in 7th or 9th place based on the current page number.
This more specific selector targets the button based on its location within the HTML tree.
How to find this path:

Open your browser's developer tools (usually F12 key).
Inspect the target button element
Right-click on the target button element.
Select Copy -> Copy JS path on chrome (or similar depending on your browser).

For point 4 you can select Copy selector or Copy JS path based on your needs.

I'm so thankful
but unfortunately it didn't work
next_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div > div.css-1omce3u > div > div > div.css-if9uys > ul > li:last-child > button'))) 
i tried this and it didn't navigate to the next page

This is just a shortcut but you can use $$() instead of typing out all of document.querySelectorAll(). $x() can be used for XPaths.

This is trickier than I thought it was going to be at first glance. The XPath for the > icon is
//ul/li[last()]//i
  ^ grab the UL
     ^ grab the child LI
        ^ that is the last LI in the list (important)
                 ^ then grab the descendant I

There's only a single UL on the page so that part is easy. Next we need to grab the last LI under that UL using last(). This is important because if you don't use last() you might get one of the left arrows instead of the right arrow. Then from there just grab the I tag descendant.
You can test this in the browser using $x("//ul/li[last()]//i") to verify it.
